# Are export const statements visible inside the file they reside?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Are `export const` statements visible inside the file they reside?

```
export const MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 20;
console.log(MAX_NAME_LENGTH); // can I do this?
```

Comment: You really could have simply tried it, couldn't you?

Comment: Given that this is just syntactic sugar for `const MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 20; export { MAX_NAME_LENGTH as MAX_NAME_LENTH }` the answer would obviously be…

Comment: Yes, I could have. My unfamiliarity with modules, and my uncertainty over unknown unknowns led me to post a question. I guess my laziness might now help other lazy developers.

Comment: ...and your comment re syntactic sugar is a lesson I and anyone else reading this will now learn. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are. The declaration is still a declaration in the scope in which it appears (e.g., the module's scope, since `export` can only appear there) and all the usual rules about the declaration apply; all `export` does is export it.

In that specific case, since it's a `const` declaration, the "usual rules" include the temporal dead zone above the declaration in which `MAX_NAME_LENGTH` cannot be used. If you'd exported a function declaration like this:

```
export function foo() {
}
```

...the "usual rules" mean you could use `foo` anywhere in your module code, because it's still hoisted. (Same for `export var x;`.)

---

(You can also test things like this with an up-to-date version of Chrome, which now supports modules. :-) )

Comment: Do you know if I can use modules in Chrome dev tools?

Comment: @Ben: Not sure what you mean by "in Chrome dev tools"...? Do you mean in an extension?

Comment: I mean the developer tools accessed via cmd+shift+i. The file-oriented nature of modules implies to me that I would have to actually create a file, load it into a web page, and observe the result, rather than say, create a snippet in Chrome dev tools, and use `import`, `export default` etc from within that.

Comment: @Ben: Ah, you literally mean in devtools. :-) I don't think so, but there are parts of devtools I've never explored. When I want to do something like this, I just dash off a file.

Comment: Thank you. This answer clarifies things for me.